# Formato correcto para enlaces en W3C

Tags: html5, validación

Tengo un sitio que tiene un pie de página donde se incluye la siguiente cadena para enlazar enlaces internos (hablo de un documento *HTML*):

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('nosotros/aviso-legal#top'); ?>" title="Aviso legal">
```

A su vez tiene este parámetro para referenciar la miga:

```
<?php echo include_partial(
    'nosotros/breadcrumbs',
    array(
        'nombreSeccion'=> 'Términos de servicio',
        'tituloSeccion'=> 'Términos de servicio'
    )
) ?>
```

Al pasar el validador *W3C* dice que este formato no es correcto, pero no me indica cual sería el correcto.

¿Podría alguien informarme cuál sería el formato compatible correcto?

Comment: la w3c valida codigo html no PHP

Comment: Asumiendo que tu usas el validor de *w3c* utilizando el link hacia tu sitio, y no el código php, entonces los errores dependerán totalmente de como el documento se identifique a sí mismo, por ejemplo si es *xhtml 1.1*, la etiqueta `<a>` debe cerrarse , en tu anterior ejemplo no está cerrada (aunque asumo que sí lo haces).Agradecería que publicarás los warnings lanzados por el validador y mejor aún, tú código , si el contenido es dinámico basta con un ejemplo concreto.

Answer (score 1):

El elemento [`HTML Anchor (<a>)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), define un hiper vínculo a una ubicación en la misma página o cualquier otra página en la Web. También se puede utilizar (en una forma obsoleta) para crear un punto punto de anclaje—a un destino para los hiper vínculos dentro del contenido de una página, de modo que los enlaces no se limitan a conectar simplemente a la parte superior de una página.

- Puede tener contenido:  [transparente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/categorias_de_contenido#Modelo_de_contenido_transparente), [dinámico](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/categorias_de_contenido#Contenido_din%C3%A1mico) (excluyendo contenido interactivo) o contenido de [párrafo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/categorias_de_contenido#Contenido_textual_o_est%C3%A1tico).
- Debe ser cerrado (`</a>`)

Ejemplos:

```
<a href="http://google.com" title="Google">Google</a>
<!-- Obsoletos -->
<a id="ancla"></a>
<a href="#ancla">Ir al anclaje</a>
```

[Mas ejemplos aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Examples)